# Azure Active Directory on .NET core on a Mac

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm following the sample code from:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/
On Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 it works fine, but when developing on my Mac, I cannot figure out why "await HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync" does not work on Mac. It crashes dotnet.
Please see screenshot on my question on Twitter: https://twitter.com/glenster75/status/883213695995699200 and was instructed to post it here:
[image]

Comment: Hey Glen, I am pointing the ASP.NET Core team to this Q- hopefully they'll be able to help.

Comment: thanks! @vibronet, I enjoyed your talk at Build and look forward to use AD a lot more now. It does need to work on a Mac too though...

Comment: Do you think that if I switch to .net core 2 preview 2 this issue could be fixed?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! I truly don't know, sorry :( I flagged your post with the asp.nwt core team, but I believe they look at SO as best effort. I suspect you'd get faster responses if you file an issue kn the core repos on github

Comment: ok, i'll do that. thanks you so much for your time

Comment: for continuity I posted an issue on github: [link](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/12726)

Comment: for tracking purposes, the Microsoft team has moved the issue in github to: [https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22172](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22172)

Comment: Can you post the error message as text, instead of an animated GIF?

Comment: Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fc7978eb590
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Comment: It's just too long so if you want to see the whole error message let me know and I can email it...